# BLE - Why do I get no callback if the Scan finds nothing?

Tags: android, callback, bluetooth-lowenergy

In my app, I want a watchdog to wake up every so often and check if we are connected to the device.  I also want the user to be able to push a button to connect right now.  Checking if we are already connected and dismissing the request works simply enough.  However, I also don't want to start a scan if a current scan is already in progress.  So I have a method that starts the scan like this:

```
void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
    if (enable) {
        //Will stop the scanner in given amount of milliseconds
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);

        mLEScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
        isScanning = true;
        Log.i("BLE_Service_Comm", "Scanning...");
    } else {
        mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
        Log.i("BLE_Service_Comm", "Scanning stopped");
    }
}
```

Note that I set "isScanning" to true.  If I receive any sort of callback, I make sure to make "isScanning" false:

```
private ScanCallback mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            isScanning = false;
            Log.i("BLE_Service_Comm", "Scan callback type " + String.valueOf(callbackType));
            Log.i("BLE_Service_Comm", "Scan callback " + result.toString());
            BluetoothDevice btDevice = result.getDevice();
            Log.i("BLE_Service_Comm", "Scan callback address " + btDevice.getAddress());
            connectToDevice(btDevice);
        }

        //Honestly don't know when it would return a "batch" like this
        @Override
        public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
            isScanning = false;
            Log.i("BLE_Service_Comm", "Batch results");
            for (ScanResult sr : results) {
                Log.i("BLE_Service_Comm", sr.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
            isScanning = false;
            Log.e("BLE_Service_Comm", "Scan failed with Error Code: " + errorCode);
        }
    };
```

Once I connect, I can find the GATT profile I want and everything works great.  When my autotimer wakes up, or the user pushes "connect" and the device is connected or "isScanning" is true, it ignores the request.

But if my scan *doesn't* find a device, mScanCallback is never run, and "isScanning" remains true permanently.  In this case, the timer waking up, or the user pushing "Connect" will do nothing, because I'll see "isScanning" as true.

Am I missing something here?  Is there a way for a ScanCallback to tell you that the scan is complete and nothing was found?  Is my method of the postDelayed Runnable that ends the scan after SCAN_PERIOD time messing anything up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just need to set "isScanning" to false in the PostDelayed Runnable.

Comment: You can mark this answer as correct so that it is helpful for other users.